# Perl script for removing pages from a pdf file based on pattern

Tags: perl, pdf-generation

We have a 3,000-page PDF file and we want to remove pages based on a pattern.

For example pagenot found in the PDF have 50 pages. Now output is like to 2,950 pages by removing 50 pages from the document.

Comment: I don't understand *"pagenot found in the PDF have 50 pages"*. Please explain

Comment: I should think "pagenot found" is the content/text on the pdf file. May I correct.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CAM::PDF;

my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new('input.pdf');
my $ttl_pgs = $pdf->numPages();

for(1..$ttl_pgs)
{
    my $pagnum = $_;
    my $pdf_cnt = $pdf->getPageContent($pagnum);
    if($pdf_cnt=~m/pages not found/i)
    {
         $pdf->deletePage($pagnum);
    }
}
$pdf->cleanoutput('output.pdf');
```